# Плавное изменение высоты, при удалении/добавлении DOM

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, vue.js

Как в **Vue** анимировать изменение высоты, когда удаляется или добавляется **DOM** элемент внутри определенного блока?

Comment: никак. Удаление нельзя анимировать. Есть много чего что нельзя анимировать. Можно написать костыль чтоб анимировался не удаляемый элемент, а как бы блок оверлей поверх него паралельно при удалении и анимировать ему высоту.

Comment: А если анимацию втиснуть перед непосредственным удалением, а на само удаление поставить задержку, ну или стартовать удаление после завершения анимации?

Answer (score 1):

Может я не совсем правильно понял вопрос, но что мешает использовать transition на элементе, который будет удаляться/появляться, при этом родитель будет автоматически менять высоту вместе с ним.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hide: false
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1.3s;
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1.3s;
}

.fade-enter {
  height: 0;
}

.fade-leave-to {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="hide=!hide">click</button>

  <transition name="fade" appear>
    <div class="red" v-if="!hide">

    </div>
  </transition>

</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что высота блока мне заранее неизвестна.

Comment: В этом случае можно использовать trasform scale

Comment: есть событие, transitionend - говорит само за себя. Удалите элемент после его возникновения

Comment: @Idushii, ну не получится же - размер меняться не будет.